# Android Dynamically added Expandablelistview return null for findviewbyid

Tags: android, null, expandablelistview

I am creating the Expandablelistview dynamically as below in which the expanded list contains edittext and checkbox.

```
ExpandableListView epView = new ExpandableListView(this);
mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
epView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
ll.addView(epView);
```

I have a submit button in my `LinearLayout ll` on submit I am trying to get the values inside the expandable list using the edittext id. I am getting the value of expanded items which is displayed in the mobile screen but the collapsed state items are returning null for findviewbyid. Can someone get me the solution for this?

Comment: A frnd of mine had done a nice tutorial Check this [link](http://coderzheaven.com/index.php/2011/04/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/)

Answer (score 0):

```
              ExpandableListView epView = new ExpandableListView(this);
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);

              mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
              epView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
              LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
              ll.addView(epView,lp );
```

Comment: add layout params to set the width and height